# xunit.console in appveyor is failing while looking for xunit.dll

Tags: c#, xunit, appveyor

I have a project under appveyor. Running the build script fails when testing begin with the following message:

`EXEC : error : Could not find file: C:\projects\Projname\test\Projname.Tests\bin\Release\xunit.dll`

I'm invoking the test runner from the build script using:

`xunit.console.clr4 test/Projname.Tests/bin/Release/Projname.Tests.dll /appveyor`

`xunit.console` is working fine locally on my machine and without looking for `xunit.dll`. Why is this happening in appveyor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what's causing the problem, so I followed what appveyor **really** does when it automatically discovers and runs tests (as opposed to what it instructs us to do in the docs).

My script that runs on the CI is now this:

`%xunit20%\xunit.console.x86 path\to\test.dll -appveyor`